# how to make ubuntu virtual host a domain name (make nameserver)

Tags: virtualhost, nameserver

I have a virtual host in ubuntu with a dedicated ip. How can I make it host a domain name or several domains for example mynewdomain.co.cc. I want to point the nameserver setup of mynewdoamin.co.cc to my virtual host. How can I do that ? I already have configured a lampp apache in this virtual host. And I can access the host with ip.

Let me know if I have to clarify more.

Comment: You are mixing up 2 completely different topics. Apache VHosts aren't in any way related to a DNS set up. In fact you can have have IP based VHosts, Port Based VHosts and Name based VHosts -- only the latter do absolutely need a working DNS setup. May I suggest you decide on one topic here, and post a second question with the other topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your virtual hosts in your Apache configuration.  See [Apache Virtual Host documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/).

Comment: yea, but don't my virtual host have to have nameserver configuration which I will set in the co.cc domain ns1 and ns2 configuration ?

Comment: The DNS servers for your *mynewdomain.co.cc* would require *A* records pointing to your dedicated IP address so clients can find your host.  Apache then uses the contents of the Host header sent by the client to select a virtual host to serve.

Comment: that means I will need to set the ns1 and ns2 for mynewdomain.co.cc to the virtual server ip ? same ip for both ns1 and ns2 ?

Comment: No you will set the ns1 and ns2 to whatever DNS you are using to host your domain.  You will create an *A* record in that DNS to point to your virtual server ip.